# Camera light flashes when the phone rings - how do I turn this off?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera, 4.3-jelly-bean, camera-flash

With Android version 4.3 for my Samsung Galaxy S3 (or perhaps just Verizon's flavor of it) my camera flash has begun to blink **very brightly** when I am receiving an incoming call.  How can I turn this off?  I've been through the settings and nothing obvious really jumps out at me.

Comment: That's certainly a weird thing! Since each manufacturer changes settings menus slightly (or a lot sometimes), it may be helpful to [edit] your question and include information about which phone you have.

Comment: I see you've included the tag for Galaxy S3, so I just made a quick edit to include that in your question text. Please [edit] to correct if I was assuming incorrectly =).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the setting, and something interesting as well:

```
Settings > Accessibility > Flash notification
```

When I came into the settings it was already unchecked, yet my phone was exhibiting behavior as if it was. I had to check the setting and exit the menus. Then I went back in to uncheck the setting and exited the menus again. This time the setting took effect - my camera light is no longer flashing.

Hope this helps others in the same situation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Once I entered the `Settings` app (on my AT&T SGS3), I had to select the `My Device` tab. If that's true of you as well, you should edit the answer to include that step.

Comment: @TreborRude On Verizon's SGS3 I did not have to take that step, but thanks for pointing out the difference on yours.